# Implementing LSM hook bprm_check_security

Tags: linux-kernel, linux, linux-security-module

Recently, I am working on developing an Application Whitelisting solution for embedded linux based on the Linux Security Framework. The main focus of my LSM is implementing the bprm_check_security hook, invoked, when a program executing in the user-space (we do not consider kernel processes). 
This hook is given a pointer of type "struct linux_binprm *bprm". This pointer includes a file pointer (including the executable file of the executed program), and a char pointer (including the name of the executed program).

Our application whitelisting solution is based on hash calculation. Accordingly, in my LSM, I use the file pointer(contained in the bprm pointer) to calculate a new hash value and store that value together with the filename (in the bprm pointer) as an entry in a list.

However, during the linux boot (before the /sbin/init is executed), there are missmatches between the filename, and the file pointer. 
For instance, in one of first executing programs, the filename in the bprm pointer is "/bin/cat", however, the file pointer in the same bprm pointer is not the actual file of /bin/cat, rather busybox.

After researching for a long time, I found out, that those files are executed by busybox to create an initial initrd, which consequently create the actual rootfs, and all of those files have the magic number RAMFS_MAGIC (stored in inode->i_sb->s_magic). So I used this number to filter those processes, however, I am not sure, whether it would be the right way or not. I would appreciate any helps.

It is to be noted that, I use the file pointer (included in the bprm pointer) to calculate the hash values, in other words, I dont read files depending on their filename or filepath from the userspace.

thanks.

```
/include/linux/binfmts.h
struct linux_binprm {
struct file * file;
const char * filename;  /* Name of binary as seen by procps */
};
```